# expo cannot resolve module

Tags: react-native, expo

Win 10 and latest expo. Have a new project set up with

```
npm install -g expo-cli
npm start
```

Everything works fine. Then add `react-native-elements` to the project together with the following code:

```
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
<Button />;
```

It show that `Unable to resolve "react-native-elements" from "screens\LinksScreen.js"`.

This is `app.json`:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Orange",
    "description": "A very interesting project.",
    "slug": "Orange",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "30.0.0",
    "platforms": ["ios", "android"],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    }
  }
}
```

And this is `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-new-project",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "expo": "^30.0.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-30.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-navigation": "^2.16.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-expo": "30.0.0"
  }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Where does the error appear? Your IDE or expo terminal output?

Answer (score 0):

Have you done an npm install for the react-native elements? That could very well be your problem.  Try

```
npm install --save react-native-elements
```

at the command line in the project folder.